# Snapping multiple objects to multiple locations using Arrays

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, snapping

Having trouble making a simple game that involves covering a grid with colored tiles. I have used Arrays to establish drag and drop functionality but cannot find a way to easily have them snap to the locations on the grid. I have made the locations on the grid into movie clips with names snapA1 through snapJ10, all in groups of 10 by letters and with instance names to match, but those clips have been removed from Arrays as they don't need to move. The problems I keep having is that any function I use only works to allow snapping to single locations. Basically I'm just looking for a short hand to allow two or more groups of objects to snap onto each other, preferably without having to brute-force code, I kid you not, 20,000 instances of the same code.
below is the code I have that so far only allows one snapping target location

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var greenArr:Array = new Array 
(greenTablet1, greenTablet2, greenTablet3, greenTablet4, greenTablet5,
greenTablet6, greenTablet7, greenTablet8, greenTablet9, greenTablet10,
greenTablet11, greenTablet12, greenTablet13, greenTablet14, greenTablet15, 
greenTablet16, greenTablet17, greenTablet18, greenTablet19, greenTablet20);


for (var i1:uint =0; i1 < greenArr.length; i1++) {
 greenArr[i1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragG);
 greenArr[i1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropG);
}


function dragG(event:MouseEvent):void {
 event.currentTarget.startDrag();
}


function dropG(event:MouseEvent):void {
 event.currentTarget.stopDrag();
}




stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopMotionG1);

function stopMotionG1(evt:MouseEvent):void {
snapInPlaceG1();
}
function snapInPlaceG1():void {
if (snapA1.hitTestObject(greenTablet1)) {
greenTablet1.x = snapA1.x;
greenTablet1.y = snapA1.y;


}}
```

Comment: So to clarify, each greenTableX corresponds to 1 snapAX object?  You can do this with only 1 instance of the code.   Are all your `greenTables` instances of the same library object?

Comment: Can you describe your grid a bit more?  (is it visible,  how many horizontal/vertical lines, do you need to create in FlashPro or could you just do it in code?)  - most likely - unless your grid and objects correspond to some background graphic and aren't just mathematically positioned you could do all this a very few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Easy. What you need is to stop using standard dragging and to devise a customized one. Then you can have as many draggable objects and as many snap points as you want with the same sized script:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    import flash.geom.Point;

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    // Main class.
    public class Snap extends Sprite
    {
        private var Circus:Vector.<Sprite>;
        private var Dots:Vector.<Point>;

        public function Snap() 
        {
            Dots = new Vector.<Point>;
            Circus = new Vector.<Sprite>;

            // Create snap points, put them on stage and keep their coordinates.
            for (var i:int = 1; i * 100 < stage.stageWidth; i++)
            {
                for (var j:int = 1; j * 100 < stage.stageHeight; j++)
                {
                    var aDot:Sprite = new Sprite;
                    var aPos:Point = new Point(i * 100, j * 100);

                    aDot.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.3);
                    aDot.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 4);
                    aDot.x = aPos.x;
                    aDot.y = aPos.y;

                    addChild(aDot);
                    Dots.push(aPos);
                }
            }

            var aCircas:int = 2 + 3 * Math.random();

            // Add random number of draggable objects.
            while (Circus.length < aCircas)
            {
                Circus.push(addCirca());
            }
        }

        // This method adds a draggable circle of random radius, color, position.
        private function addCirca():Sprite
        {
            var result:Sprite = new Sprite;

            result.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0);
            result.graphics.beginFill(0x1000000 * Math.random(), 0.5);
            result.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20 + 20 * Math.random());

            result.x = stage.stageWidth * Math.random();
            result.y = stage.stageHeight * Math.random();

            addChild(result);

            result.buttonMode = true;
            result.useHandCursor = true;
            result.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);

            return result;
        }

        // *** DRAGGING AN ITEM ** //

        // Snap radius.
        private var toleRance:int = 20

        // Mouse offset.
        private var offx:Number = 0;
        private var offy:Number = 0;

        // Dragged object.
        private var TheDrag:Sprite;

        private function startDragging(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // Get the dragged object reference.
            TheDrag = e.currentTarget as Sprite;

            // Bring it to front.
            setChildIndex(TheDrag, numChildren - 1);

            // Record the mouse offset. If you comment the next 2 lines
            // the object will just snap to mouse by its center.
            offx = TheDrag.x - mouseX;
            offy = TheDrag.y - mouseY;

            // Watch the object position every frame.
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);

            // Subscribe for certain events that mean the end of dragging.
            stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, stopDragging);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
        }

        private function onFrame(e:Event):void
        {
            // Get new object (x,y) according to the mouse position.
            var aPos:Point = new Point;

            aPos.x = mouseX + offx;
            aPos.y = mouseY + offy;

            // Browse through the list of snap points.
            for (var i:int = 0; i < Dots.length; i++)
            {
                // Snap to a point within tolerance pixels radius.
                if (Point.distance(aPos, Dots[i]) < toleRance)
                {
                    aPos = Dots[i];
                    break;
                }

                // If there are no points withing the given radius,
                // then the object will use mouse positioning. 
            }

            TheDrag.x = aPos.x;
            TheDrag.y = aPos.y;
        }

        private function stopDragging(e:Event):void
        {
            TheDrag = null;

            // Stop monitoring.
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);

            // Stop waiting for events to cancel dragging.
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, stopDragging);
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as a follow up to this is there a way to make it so only one clip from one array can stack onto a clip from another array

Comment: @LeonardRodriguez Not really sure what do you mean. You asked for many-to-many - you have many-to-many. One-to-many is a many=1-to-many case.